# Añadir CSS a una tabla creada de manera dinámica Laravel

Tags: php, html, jquery, css, laravel

Muy buenas. Tengo una tabla cuyos datos son rellenados a través de una llamada ajax a través del siguiente código:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Call the dataTables jQuery plugin
$(document).ready(function()
  {
    $("#dataTable").DataTable({

        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "<?php echo route($datatable); ?>",
        "iDisplayLength": 10,
        "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]], 
        "aLengthMenu": [ // set available records per page
                [ 10, 25, 50,  -1],
                [ 10, 25, 50, "Todos"]
        ],
         "oLanguage": {
                    "sSearch": "Buscar:",
                    "sLengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_",
                    "sInfoEmpty": "",
                    "sInfo":"Total _TOTAL_ registros",
                    "sInfoFiltered": "",
                    "sEmptyTable":  "No hay datos disponibles",//"No data available in table",
                    "sZeroRecords": "No se encontraron registros",//"No matching records found",
                    "oPaginate": 
                    {
                        "sPrevious": "<-",//"Prev",
                        "sNext": "->",//"Next",
                        "sPage": "Pag.",//"Page",
                        "sPageOf": "de",//"of"
                    }
                },
            "aoColumnDefs": [
                { 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [7] },
                { "bSearchable": false, "aTargets": [ 7 ] },
                 
                { "sWidth": "10%", "aTargets": [0] },
                { "sWidth": "10%", "aTargets": [1] },
                { "sWidth": "10%", "aTargets": [2] },
                { "sWidth": "10%", "aTargets": [3] },
                { "sWidth": "20%", "aTargets": [4] },
                { "sWidth": "15%", "aTargets": [5] },
                { "sWidth": "10%", "aTargets": [6] },
                { "sWidth": "15%", "aTargets": [7] }
            ]
      
    })
  });
```

Esto está dentro de una página creada por laravel y el código de la tabla dentro del view es el siguiente:

```
  <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                        <th>ID</th>
                                            <th>RUT</th>
                                            <th>Nombre</th>
                                            <th>Correo</th>
                                            <th>Telefono:</th>
                                            <th>Asignado el</th>
                                            <th>Asignado por:</th>
                                            <th>Opciones</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>     
                                        
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
```

Los datos se van llenando con un Output Array. Lo que necesito es señalar la fila en la tabla que tenga la fecha de hoy. Para esto mi intención era añadir una pequeña línea de css en cada 'tr' que tuviera la fecha actual luego de comparar las fechas en el while que va mostrando los datos. El problema es que con este código los 'tr' y los 'td' se van creando de manera dinámica y no he dado con la manera de añadirles una nueva clase para editarlos con css. Tengo muy poca experiencia en laravel y estoy viendo el código de una página ya hecha por lo que de ahí mi confusión. En la ruta del datatable se donde se extraen los datos no encuentro nada del formato de las tablas, solo los datos que se van extrayendo de la base de datos.

Había intentado con un pequeñito script en el momento en que se extrae la fecha de la base de datos y compararla con la actual que añadiera una nueva clase al tr. Pero eso me daba error y la tabla no mostraba los datos.

Comment: puedes mostrar el html resultado del plugin??? un fragmento para analisar que estructura de datatable estas usando... ya que datatable. net tiene una amalgama de layout que varia dependiendo de como muestras la informacion...

Comment: creo que puedes usar el https://datatables.net/manual/data/renderers y agregarle a la celda un input hidden con la fecha. y trabajar en base a ese dato y ese nodo el input puedes ponerle un name="fecha_hoy_13_07_2021" donde esto: 13_07_2021 es el dato de tu ajax o algo asi parecido... el problema es que sin un html de tu render es dificil darte una respuesta funcional.

Answer (score 1):

Cual es el codigo de tu ruta de la llamada de ajax? Por que podrias añadir las clases que necesites desde la respuesta, o pues efectivamente hacer un script despues de la construccion de la tabla que recorra cada tr verifique la fecha y si coincide agregue la clase. Algo asi,

```
const fecha = new Date();
var fechahoy = hoy.toLocaleDateString();
$('table tr .fecha').each(function(){
if (this.innerText =  fechahoy){
    this.parent().parent().addClass("marca")
// alcanzamos el tr
        });
```

Comment: esto no funciona cuando manejas tablas del plugin datatable.net